# How can I preserve leading zeros when reading a number and printing it later?

Tags: c++, integer, cout

I want to `cout` an integer starting 0. For example, 0123456789.
But when I print it out, it only display `123456789` instead of `0123456789`.

How can I solve this problem?

Below is my sample code:

```
sample.txt

0125961349
01359395930
019349130
```

I parse 1 of the contact number into an object, eg: 019349130. hence:

```
cout << cp.contactNum << endl;
```

and the final result is

```
19349130
```

This is not the result I want. And you can see I have different length for the integer, I cannot use the leading zero solution to solve it or else it will become something like `0019349130`.

Comment: It depends, show us some code.

Comment: that's a string formatting problem. all integers have infinite leading (and trailing) zeroes. if you wan them to be displayed, then you'll have to tell C to properly format the output.

Comment: @MuertoExcobito no, it's not the way i want. I want it to print out fully same from my text file.

Comment: @ChuahChengJun - you should explain the actual problem in the question, because as it is written, it is a duplicate of the one I tagged.

Comment: @Jarod42 for some reason, i need to use int for this.

Comment: You mention *"contact number"*. Are these telephone numbers? Telephone numbers are not integers and should not be handled as such. They are strings, which happen to contain digits. It sounds like you should be using strings.

Comment: @GregHewgill just want to know, despite using string, is there any possible method?

Comment: @ChuahChengJun You can use any method you want. There is no "one right way". If you don't want to use a string, you could use another integer that codes the number of leading zeroes. You could even use base 11 if you want, and use the eleventh digit to represent a leading zero. Do it however you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must parse the numbers into a string or const char* else you lose information about the heading 0.  So the type of contactNum should be std::string instead of int.