# leading 0's are not getting read from file

Tags: c++, file-handling

I am reading the content of a file character by character:

The file has:

```
000001111100000
```

When I use this code to read

```
int content;// converting to char will result in proper output.
std::ifstream fin;
fin.open("zero_one");
fin>>content;
while (!fin.eof())
{
    std::cout<<content;
    fin>>content;
}
fin.close();
```

I get the output as: `1111100000` (the leading zeros are not present) but the trailing zeros are present.

The concern is: as I am using `>>` operator to read then, why don't I get the leading zeros in output whereas as I get the trailing zeros in output.

Also, If I convert the `int` to `char` for `content` variable then the output is same as the content of the file. Why is this so? As far as I know, the only difference between the `char` and `int` is the size in bytes of the variable.

Comment: `int` only stores the value of numbers. `000001111100000` and `1111100000` have the same value. You need to read the number as a string if the actual character representation is important for your use case.

Comment: "As far as I know, the only difference between the char and int is the size in bytes of the variable." That's true for the types int and char, but the >> input operator is overloaded differently for those types.

Comment: Here is a link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30580903/how-can-i-preserve-leading-zeros-when-reading-a-number-and-printing-it-later

Comment: Interpreted as an `int`eger, "01" and "1" is the same thing.

Comment: Would you really expect "01" to read as a different integer from "1"? Sure, you'd expect them to be different *characters* but surely those different character strings encode the same integer -- the number one.

Comment: A [user fluent in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5411888/amit-upadhyay)  would not need to post this.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux That identifies the same issue but doesn’t answer “why”.

Comment: @chux comment++; but, you are underestimating the power of the [Dunning–Kruger effect](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning–Kruger_effect).

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I knew how to preserve leading zeros and that's what I mentioned too. My main concern was as I am reading the content using the loop then why does it not show me the leading zeros. And I don't found answer there also.

Comment: @AmitUpadhyay If you read an `int` from a file, it will read the entire number at once, not one digit at a time.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: Actually, `011` and `11` are not the same.  The first one is an octal constant, with a value of 9.  Unless the `ios_base` flag `basefield` is first set to decimal.

Comment: @BenVoigt Huh, you’re right. I assumed based on the question that it didn’t do that for stream I/O because otherwise a different value would be extracted.

Comment: @DanielH: I'm having some trouble finding documentation of the default value... possibly `basefield` *is* set to decimal in OP's code.

Comment: Nah, it's not implementation dependent.  The Standard (all versions from C++03 through post-C++17 draft) requires the initial flags to be `skipws | dec`.  Finally found it documented at `std::basic_ios::init()`, under *Postconditions*.

Comment: You have avoided the most insidious effect of `while (!fin.eof())`, but you've left yourself open to infinite loop on invalid input because you only check for end of file, which the program may never reach if it finds bad a bad value. Recommend `while (fin>>content)` as a replacement.

Comment: @BenVoigt Thanks; I had given up searching for the default and determined [by experiment](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d9fd848780a0c03f) that it was at least sometimes enabled by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `content` is an `int`, it reads the data as a *single* integer: you get an `int` with the value 1111100000. If `content` is a `char`, it reads each character separately.

You can see the difference if, in the `while` loop, you say `std::cout<<content<<'\n';` instead of just `std::cout<<content;`. Then if `content` is an `int` you will see one line containing 1111100000, but if it’s a `char` you will see 15 lines, one for each character of input.

If you put spaces between each character of the input file, they would be read as separate `int`s and the results would be the same, but there would still be an important difference: the values of the `char`s aren’t `char(0)` and `char(1)`, but `'0'` and `'1'` (`0x30` and `0x31`, respectively), the ASCII values of the corresponding digits. The `int`s on the other hand would actually be `0` or `1`.